# Product notation for algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-modules

See the definition of "Graded G-algebra" on this page: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed+G-algebra

What is meant by the notation $L_gL_h\subseteq L_{gh}$ in condition (i)? In particular the product $L_gL_h$ of projective $\mathbb{k}$-modules.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means that if you multiply an element of $L_g$ with an element of $L_h$ you get an element of $L_{gh}$.

Comment: So $L_gL_h=\{v_1v_2:v_1\in L_g,v_2\in L_h\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if that's what they meant.